# Tradução de Inbox e Achievements

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

As palavras INBOX e Achievements não estão traduzidas. O resto da tab que é aberta sim, então acredito que seja um bug.

INBOX: Caixa de entrada. Espero que caiba.

[image: inbox]

ACHIEVEMENTS: Conquistas

[image: achoevements]

Answer (score 4):

De facto, se pararmos o rato sobre cada icon o tempo necessário para aparecer a legenda, vamos constatar que em ambos os casos, a mensagem de ajuda já apresenta a tradução, pelo que a mesma deveria ser aplicada no título de cada uma das janelas:

### INBOX

[image: Captura de Tela]

Que ficaria então:

> Caixa de Entrada
>
> [image: Captura de Tela]

### ACHIEVEMENTS

[image: Captura de Tela]

Que ficaria então:

> Realizações Recentes
>
> [image: Captura de Tela]